# How to remove git account from local machine and add new account

Tags: git, github

I have a github account which is configured in my windows pc. Now I have created a new Github account and want to use the new one.

How will I remove my old account from my windows pc and add the new github account ?

**NOTE:** I have edited the gitconfig file and added the new user email and username there. But the public key still contains the old user email !!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**For windows machine**

**you can manage windows credential for doing this**

go to search button then write

**manage windows credential**

then you will find a button **double click** it

**then remove your current windows credential**

after that when you are using git again **git authentication will be asked**

then you will enter your new **github id**

**Next you need to edit .gitconfig file**

**file path will be like**

```
C:\Users\Imu
```

here **imu** is my user name
it will be different in yours

Now edit **.gitconfig** file using text editor like **nodepad++** or **sublime text** with ur current id information

**hoping it helps**

Comment: I can not see any credential for git. There are some other credentials like Microsoft Account, Microsoft Office Account, Windows Live etc.

Here is the path where I found windows credentials:
`Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager`
Which one should I remove from there ?

Comment: there will be a row like

**git:https://github.com**

if not then currently there is no account sign in from the machine

Comment: or you can use this command in cmd

**git config --global --unset-all**

Comment: I found this after hours of searching! Thanks so much mine now works too

Answer (score 20):

You can use Credential Manager for adding/deleting/modifying existing Github accounts. Steps:

1. Go to Start -> Type 'Credential Manager' -> Open Credential Manager
2. Below window will be displayed

[image]

3. Go to 'Windows Credentials' -> Generic Credentials
4. You will see an entry for Github

[image]

5. Click on the entry -> You will see below options

[image]

6. You can edit the entry -> Add new username and password -> Click on Save

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

Edit 2:

It seems like you are trying to generate a new SSH key for your new account. If that's the case and you think your public key is specified for your old account, you shouldn't worry acording to [this post](https://superuser.com/q/516912). The comment at the end of your publc key is JUST a comment. You can generate a new one with a different comment if you want to.

Original content :

If you are using Bash, you can use your favorite text editor and open the .gitconfig file yourself and remove the credentials you don't want. It is located (in Bash) at "~/.gitconfig".

e.g.:

```
nano ~/.gitconfig
```

I'm pretty sure there is a command you could do for this, but this is how I would do it.

Edit:

Here is a command line that could do it :

```
git config {--global|--system|--local} --edit
```

This command line will do exactly the same as the first command line I mentionned except that this one is working not only on Bash and you don't have to know the location of the file by heart. It will use your default text editor.

```
{--global|--system|--local}
```

Means only one of the three options. Use only one depending on the config file you want to edit. Personaly I would not edit the system one, so just look in your local ones (for the repositories you need to) and in the gloabal one.

P.S.: I assume you are using command lines. If you don't, I suggest you to try it.

Comment: I have updated the config file already. But when I generate publick key to add in github, it still shows the old public key which contains the email of old github account. !!!

Answer (score 3):

run

```sh
nano ~/.gitconfig
```

delete unnecessary items which are other than your name and email.

save

check for git config

run:

```sh
git config -l
```

or

```sh
git config --global -l
```

Answer (score 1):

Just changing name and email on **.gitconfig** didn't work here.

It took effect only after running:

`git credential-manager-core configure`

Comment: It works for me but it keeps asking the credentials, how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is just to change the GitHub account used on your local machine by this command:

open your terminal and write these commands

```
git config --global user.name "your new username"
git config --global user.email "your new email"
```

Then Git will use these credentials instead of the old one