# Error after entering 'git push -u origin main'

Tags: git

I have once already done a local git with the CLI but with a different account.
For reference I used this video: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVRQoVRzMIY&ab_channel=TechWithTim](http://Here)

That account works, but I wanted to create a new one. After that, I successfully created the new one and typed:

> git config --global user.name "Your Name"

and

> git config --global user.email "youremail@yourdomain.com"

When I did this for my first account I was able to

> git push -u origin main

without having any problems, however, now that I have done it again for my second account I received this error:

> remote: Permission to lunAr-creator/learning_python.git denied to Slow-Scallion4183.
> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/lunAr-creator/learning_python.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

**Slow-Scallion3184 is my first account, lunAr-creator is my second**

Is there a way I can fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: After I tried what was suggested in the comments I just received this error:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed)

Comment: yeah sorry i tried what they recommended in the accepted answer but it just returned the error that i have added into the original question

Comment: would it be worth uninstalling and re-installing git-bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I had the wrong credentials saved on the credential manager.

Once I had removed my old credentials using the ***Manage Windows Credentials***, I was able to add the new ones during the push.

Here is where I found the solution: [How to remove git account from local machine and add new account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43573790/how-to-remove-git-account-from-local-machine-and-add-new-account)